# Generating and storing random numbers in array in c

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have to make an array containing 25 random numbers using a function to define the random numbers but keep getting it to either display only one number at a time (instead of all of them cell by cell) or simply displaying incorrectly i.e. 0. Here is what I have so far.

*edit* Code changed to correct stupid mistakes I missed rushing, however still unsure how to call funct as I am getting "too few arguments for funct 'get_value', apologies if this seems trivial but I am extremely new to coding thank you for your time.

```
int get_value (int t);
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int temp[25], n;
    for(n=0; n<25; n++)
       {temp[n] = rand() %(40)+60;
        printf("value of %d at cell %d \n", n, temp[n]);}
    return 0;
}

  //function get_value()
  //needs to return rand # <-> 60 and 100 seed rand
  //use rand %40+60 to ensure value is <-> 60 and 100

int get_value (int t)
{
    return rand() %(40)+60;
}
```

Comment: `temp[t]`??? What's `t`. Should be `n`. Also, `printf(....temp[n]`). Also, brackets around `for` loop....

Comment: and `temp[25]` on the next line is accessing beyond the bounds of the array - should be `temp[n]`

Comment: This won't even compile. There's no variable `t` where you have `temp[t]`. And for some reason, you're printing `temp[25]` every time in the loop. Don't you mean to print `temp[n]`?

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There's really not much excuse for posting code that doesn't compile unless your question is about why it doesn't compile — and then the question should include the compilation error messages.  Also, make sure you have compiler warnings enabled and fix all the warnings.  At this stage in your career, if the compiler warns you, it is because you've made a mistake.  (Actually, it stays like that after 30 years of C coding too — almost always, if the compiler warns me, it is because I've made a mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors
 for loop should be like this

```
for(n=0; n<25; n++)
 {
  temp[n] = get_value(n);  //in your prog u have written temp[t], t isnt defined
           printf("value at cell %d is %d \n", n, temp[n]);
 }   // you also missed the braces
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value to temp[t], but you haven't declared t. In any case, it should be temp[n].

The scope of the variable t is only in your get_value function.

For more information about [scopes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //I think here's what you want to do.
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int temp, i, j, h;
        int num_array[40];
        int i_need_25[25];

        //here's how im getting random numbers without repeating a number.
        //first, fill the array with numbers between
        for(i = 0; i < 41; i++)
        {
            num_array[i] = i + 60;
        }

        //then here's how we shuffle it
        for(i = 0; i < 41; i++)
        {
            j = rand() % 41;
            temp = num_array[j];
            num_array[j] = num_array[i];
            num_array[i] = temp;
        }

        //final process is to print the first 25 elements as you have said you need 25.
        for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", num_array[i]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");

        //or you can also store the first 25 elements on separate array variable.
        for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            i_need_25[i] = num_array[i];
            printf("%d ", i_need_25[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```